# React and Material UI, general understanding of props and nesting of components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, styling

I use Material ui (@mui/material) for a react application.
I just think I didn't completely grasp how the components work "together", e.g if you nest a MenuItem inside a Box or a Link inside a  element... which styles are predefined in e.g Typography then and which styles from what component will apply? The Link element or Typography?

what will be inherited from the parent element? and so on..

Answer (score 1):

this may not be useful input but, in my experience with the above example, the typography content inherits the links properties like the `textDecoration` property while maintaining its own properties as well